# JQuery selectmenu set selected index on change

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the selected index of a select box / [selectMenu](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu) on *change* back to the first option.

Here is my code so far

```
    $obj = $("<select class='class1' />");
    $obj.append("<option value='-1' selected='selected' class='icon1'>default</option>");
    $obj.append("<option value='0' class='icon2'>opt1</option>");
    $obj.append("<option value='1' class='icon2'>opt2</option>");
    $obj.append("<option value='2' class='icon2'>opt3</option>");

    $("#container").append($obj);
    $obj.selectmenu({
        transferClasses: true,
        icons: [
            {find: '.icon1', icon: 'ui-icon-flag'},
            {find: '.icon2', icon: 'ui-icon-plus'}
        ],
        change: function(){
            // doesn't work $(this).find("option:first").attr("selected","selected");
            // doesn't work $(this).selectedIndex = 0;
            // doesn't work $(this).val(-1);
            // doesn't work $(this).val("-1");
            // doesn't work $(this).val("");
        }
    });
```

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/GXtpC/85/), The top dropdown menu I have altered. If you change the value, and re-open the dropdown menu the selected value 'jumps' to the one i changed it to. I want it to be there once i select any value.

Comment: After lookin at the selectmenu code itself it appears that when the selectmenu is changed you are only changing the javascript generated overlay and the changes are not being seen by the form control behind the scenes. Which leads me to question how this would work when submitting the form? switch from option index 0 to the last option and inspect the page... you'll see that the last li in the ul list is 'selected' but the first option in the selectmenu is still selected... I haven't looked at how the code handles form submission... just an observation i thought i'd share.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $('select :first-child').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CzRWD/

or if you'd rather use `$(this)` you can do:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).children(":first").attr('selected','selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CzRWD/1/

**UPDATE**

After a bit of playing around and quite a lot of research, I discovered that the way to change the index in the selectmenu plugin is to use the `value` property and pass in the value of the item you want to select.

This is done inside the change event:

```
$(this).selectmenu("value",$(this).children(":first").val());
```

Here's a working example using your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GXtpC/86/

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those work for the plugin I have listed I am using. I can verify the underlying selectbox has been changed, but this does not trigger an update from the plugin.

Comment: @rlemon - please see my update. This is now working as you require :)